# How to center align row content within a container div using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am doing an assignment for a Web Development course using css, html and bootstrap. I need to make a website and I am having some issues with the layout, I am using bootstrap cards (with images) within container and row div but the 3 cards in the row aren't aligned at the center of the col, there is some space left on the right side of the col as you can see in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc51g.png).

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row ">

                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="card text-center " style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="imgs\products\cameras\1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Canon EOS Rebel T7</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Price : Rs. 37000.00</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>    

                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="imgs\products\cameras\2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Fujifilm X-T3</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Price : Rs. 34000.00</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="imgs\products\cameras\3.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Nikon D5600</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Price : Rs. 43000.00</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to know if there is any way to center align the card in the col div using css or bootstrap?

I would also like to know how to make all the card the same size (width and height) even if the images inside them are different sizes, as you can see in [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRYJk.png) the last 2 cards are of different sizes because of the different image sizes.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you used an inline styling of width:18rem? If you remove the inline styling, the columns line up perfectly in the centre of the container.

Comment: Are u expecting like this: https://jsfiddle.net/weczj8od/

Comment: @CharleneVas That was there already when I copied code for the card from the bootstrap website, I thought they might not work if I remove the inline styling. I tried removing them now and the card lined up correctly in its parent element, I should have tried removing that before only, my bad.

Comment: @AmareshSM I want all the cards to be the same height even if the size of the images differ to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first question:

Just use `col-4 d-flex justify-content-center` on your col definition.
By doing this, the card should be aligned in the middle of the col, [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaevA.jpg).
Blue = container, purple = column, green = card.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thank you, now it is aligned center. What does the `d-flex` class do? I had used only `justify-content-center` before and that didn't work.

Comment: I guess you have to apply d-flex in order to make it a flex container at first.
`justify-content-center` is meant to work with d-flex, so if you let d-flex out you do not have a proper flex item and the alignment in center can not work the right way.